# Run Up Expenses

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

It is standard English to write:

> He ran up ***a phone bill***.
>   He ran up ***a  debt***.

So, a bill and a debt could be used with the phrase "run up".
Would it okay to write:

> He ran up ***a charge***.
>   He ran up ***an expense***.

, using "charge" and "expense" as objects for "run up"?

EDIT:  a little bit of rewrite.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you're asking. The first two aren't really "in the same spirit" themselves. You can switch to *He ran up a huge debt*, but not *He ran up a lot of phone bill*. And unlike "phone bill", if you want to use "huge" in conjunction with "expenses", you must discard the indefinite article *He ran up huge expenses*. This does look rather like just a request for us to proofread your third example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I rewrote the question slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the phrase "run up" implies a *number* of different charges; you run up a phone bill by making many expensive calls, or a debt by making a number of charges to your credit card.

For that reason, I don't think "a charge" or "an expense" are valid objects.

Comment: I think you could just about say *"I stayed at the Hilton last night and ran up quite a charge on my company credit card"*, but it would be stretching the usage a bit. For me personally, singular ***an expense*** doesn't really work in *any* context (my ***expenses*** are composed of multiple ***expense items***). Whatever - overall I think this answer represents sound advice.

Comment: You're quite right; in that example, "a charge" is the cumulation of a number of different expenses, so it matches the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

"Run up"  means accumulating over time, and usually involves many small transactions building into an (often unexpected) larger amount.

So you couldn't really "run up" a bill in a McDonald's (because you order and pay for everything together) but you could "run up" a mobile phone bill over the course of a month.

A 'charge' or an 'expense' are single items so you wouldn't use "run up" with them.

Comment: But, if "charges" are considered as a whole and "expenses" are also considered as a whole would "He ***ran up charges***" and "He ***ran up expenses***" be acceptable?

Comment: @meatie Yes, both OK. There are also cases where "charge" (singular) could be OK, where it refers to a single payment for multiple items: "Over the month, I ran up a huge charge for internet access on my mobile phone" but charge is more often used as a single one-off payment: "The charge for parking here is £2.50"

Comment: I think it's idiomatically quite natural to *run up* a restaurant (or supermarket) bill, since such bills are *accumulated* from multiple sub-items.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to say "too *many* expenses", not "too *much* expenses". Then

> He ran up too many expenses.

I think it is OK but it sounds a bit odd.
But if you think of it as running up the phone bill and the electric bill and the water bill (the expenses) then it makes sense.

Comment: How about "He ran up ***a lot of expenses***."?